# What does Jesus mean when he said you are all gods?

Tags: psalms

Jesus seem to be quoting

http://biblehub.com/text/psalms/82-6.htm

In the psalm, Yahweh, had a speech to other gods, that they are all sons of Elyon.

In John 10:34 what was Jesus try to teach when he said that you are all gods?

Is he trying to say that Elyon did have many sons? And that he is one of them?

Jesusl also said that it is written in your law. The thing is, psalm isn't exactly law books. Only the torah is the law book. So why Jesus said that Psalm is a law book.

http://biblehub.com/text/john/10-34.htm

Answer (score 0):

In the previous verse, the Jews had accused Jesus of blasphemy, because he had said (John 10:30) "`I and my Father are one`":

> [John 10:33](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/John-Chapter-10/): The Jews answered him, saying, For a good work we stone thee not; but for blasphemy; and because that thou, being a man, makest thyself God.

The author of John has Jesus respond by citing [Psalm 82:6](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Psalms-Chapter-82/). First century Judaism was strictly monotheistic, so neither our author nor the Jews could interpret the Psalm as referring to the assembly of gods. Taken out of context, the citation implies that God had been describing all people as gods, in which case it could not be blasphemy for a man to speak of himself as the Son of God. Although Jesus has cleverly countered the claim of blasphemy, the Jews try to hold him, but he eludes them (John 10:39).

An inadvertent clue that the author was not a Jew is that he refers to "***your*** law" but he was no doubt aware that the Psalms were not part of the Law, although he strengthens the case Jesus is putting by referring to it as such.

Comment: An inadvertent clue that the author was not a Jew is that he refers to "your law" — How so? The author did not say it; Jesus did. The author is merely narrating, recording, or recounting Jesus’ speech.

Comment: @SimplyaChristian Perhaps approximately. But, would you remember whether someone said "your law" or just "the law" decades ago? If not, would you use the words most culturally attuned to your own context?

Comment: I agree with @SimplyaChristian - I'd call that 'authorial clue' suggestion a stretch, when the phrase seems more likely a figure of speech. For instance, if I were in a similar debate with a fellow Christian over a theological point, it would be perfectly natural for me to say **"Doesn't your Bible say..."** - this is not a suggestion that I don't have a Bible or find any belonging with the same group, but rather makes the point that the individual I'm talking to should take ownership and deeper consideration of the text I'm highlighting.